# linux cp cannot stat 'no such file or directory' when using | in adb

Tags: linux, bash, shell, adb

in phone i installed busybox and using adb command on ubuntu
i want to list file name and change

in dir /mnt/shared/Pictures  asdf14 , ddr.txt exists

so typed

adb shell busybox find /mnt/shared/Pictures -name asd* | sed -e 'p' -e 's/asd/kkk/' | xargs -n 2 cp

but error works : cp: cannot stat '/mnt/shared/Pictures/asdf14' : No such file or directory

when cut xargs parts, "adb shell busybox find /mnt/shared/Pictures -name asd* | sed -e 'p' -e 's/asd/kkk/' it shows

/mnt/shared/Pictures/asdf14

/mnt/shared/Pictures/kkkf14

it says the file directory is not wrong and exists definitely

when add string to txt too i used
adb shell busybox find /mnt/shared/Pictures -name asd* | echo > /mnt/shared/Pictures/ddr.txt
OR adb shell busybox find /mnt/shared/Pictures -name asd* -exec echo {} > /mnt/shared/Pictures/ddr.txt

but error occurs /mnt/shared/Pictures/ddr.txt : No such file or directory

it exists and occurs when command ls or find.

it works when i type directory all.
adb shell cp /mnt/shared/Pictures/asdf14 /mnt/shared/Pictures/asdf14444
it works.

the error occurs when using |

how can i fix it? i want to use echo or cp from listed directory
please help

i cannot use 'rename' in busybox

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You should take the [tour] and read [ask].  Then edit your question and format it so it is easier to read.  Ex. put your commands in code format.  Right now it is borderline gibberish.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @james-kim does the answer below helps to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the output of `find` and `sed` commands are ok, the `xargs` one is executed in your ubuntu machine, that's why you get

```
No such file or directory
```

error.

You should try to wrap the entire commands with double quotes so that everything will be executed on the emulator/device.

```
adb shell "busybox find /mnt/shared/Pictures -name asd* | sed -e 'p' -e 's/asd/kkk/' | xargs -n 2 cp"
```